# jquery multi autocomplete with remote source, showing the results on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

I'd like to wrap standard jQuery UI autocomplete with jQuery plugin for multi-value autocomplete. Everything works good, except one small thing. I'd like to show suggestions on focus. How should I modify my code?

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myautocomplete = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            source: null,
            minLength: 0,
            separator: ", "
        };

        var o = {};
        $.extend(o, defaults, options);

        var split = function(val) { return val.split(/,\s*/); };
        var extractLast = function(term) { return split(term).pop(); };

        if (o.source == null) return this;

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: o.source,
                        data: { term: extractLast(request.term) },
                        success: function(data) {
                            response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                return { label: item.Name };
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                search: function() {
                    return extractLast(this.value).length > o.minLength;
                },
                focus: function() {

                        //$(this).trigger('keydown.autocomplete');
                        $(this).data("autocomplete").search($(this).val());
                    //return false;
                },
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    terms.pop();
                    terms.push(ui.item.label);
                    terms.push("");
                    this.value = terms.join(o.separator);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I've tried everything that you see inside focus handler.

Comment: I think jQuery autocomplete is having a minimum character length before suggesting anything. You can set minimum character length to 0. Hope this helps.

Comment: As you can see on listing, I've already tried this. No effect

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
    var showSuggestions = function() {
        var searchString = extractLast(this.value);
        if (searchString.trim().length == 0) {
            searchString = "[GetAll]";
        }

        $(this).autocomplete("search", searchString);
    };

    $(this).focus(showSuggestions).click(showSuggestions);
```

And on the sever I am checking if it is [GetAll] I consider this is empty string